# Memory corruption in the last byte

Tags: c

I have a function that returns a pointer to a structure as the following :

```
//header file
typedef struct {
        unsigned char *buffer;
        uint8_t       len;
} T_ABC_PACKET
```

in the main file, I create a pointer to a function and tries to print this

```
T_ABC_PACKET *pct = NULL;
pct = function_that_return_the_packet;
printf("value of packet is %s \n", pct->buffer);
```

the result is always consistent in the printing function. I expect the buffer to have an 8 byte, and the last byte is always a corrupted memory.
**value is 10000357`�2U**

but if I print the buffer inside the function :

```
T_ABC_PACKET* function_that_return_the_packet {

T_ABC_PACKET *pct = NULL;
char string_temp[80];
//some more initialization...
pct->buffer = (unsigned char *)string_temp;
pct->len = 5;
printf("value of packet is %s \n", pct->buffer);
return pct;
}
```

the value printed in the function is **10000357f**. Only the last character is corrupted.
This always provide a consistent value, no many times I run the program, only the last character is corrupted in the caller of the function.
I understand one possible case is memory leak, but I tried to check carefully and I can not find any leak. How do I get the pct->buffer to have everything correctly?

Comment: Are you allocating memory for "pct" inside the function.

Comment: Just a tip for asking questions: you should generally provide a [short, self contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) so people can best understand your problem. Otherwise we can't be sure that the snippets you post actually contain the problem.

Comment: You've deleted the exact line that's causing the problem. Whatever "some more initialisation" is, it's doing something very illegal. Please show all the relevant code next time, including the bit that's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are returning a pointer to a local variable which is undefined behavior, `string_temp` is local to `function_that_return_the_packet` and will not exist after you exit that function.

As Daniel suggested using [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) is probably the simplest way to fix the problem:

```
pct->buffer = strdup(string_temp);
```

Just make sure you check that it did not fail. You could of course also use `malloc` and then `strcpy`.

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour : if it is undefined behavior, why only the last character is corrupted? and how am I supposed to fix the error above so that I can have the value of the packet correctly?

Comment: @xambo "undefined behavior" means just that: the behavior is undefined. So there's no (to the programmer) reason behind which bytes are corrupted. Maybe if you run it tomorrow, all the bytes will be. It's *undefined*.

Comment: @xambo It is undefined behavior so you can have no expectations as to the results. I also updated with a solution, there may be other issues as well without a SSCCE it is hard to know.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix the undefined behavior of returning a pointer to local (see Shafik Yaghmour answer) you still have undefined behavior: it appears that the buffer is not null-ternminated, so `%s` format specifier reads past it, and stops only when it finds an unrelated `\0`.

If you know that the buffer's length cannot exceed eight, you can copy its content up to `pct->len` into a char buffer, theninsert a terminator at the end:

```
char tmpBuf[9]; // max length is 8, plus one for null ternminator
memcpy(tmpBuf, pct->buffer, pct->len);
tmpBuf[pct->len] = '\0';
printf("value of packet is %s \n", tmpBuf);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the source of the problem:

```
pct->buffer = (unsigned char *)string_temp;
```

'string_temp' is allocated on the stack.  When function returns, it is destroyed somewhere later, or not, as in your case, except last byte.

You should:

Use `strdup()` instead of assignment in that line.

When you are done with whole structure, use `free()` to release that string before releasing whole structure.